Displaying an Overlay on Top of All Views Including Sheets in SwiftUI
I am implementing an overlay to display error messages and I want the overlay to be displayed on top of every view including sheets. The following code works for normal views but not for sheets. I read about using Window Scene and using UIHostingController but I am wondering if there is a simpler way of handling these situations.
@main
struct LearnApp: App {
    
    @State private var errorWrapper: ErrorWrapper?
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                ContentView()
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom, content: {
                Text(errorWrapper?.error.localizedDescription ?? "")
            })
            .environment(\.showError, ShowErrorAction(action: showError))
        }
    }
    
    private func showError(error: Error, guidance: String) {
        errorWrapper = ErrorWrapper(error: error, guidance: guidance)
    }
}

Usage is shown below:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    @Environment(\.showError) private var showError
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Throw Error") {
                showError(SampleError.operationFailed, "Operation has failed.")
            }
        }
}

